# Compare getline() to predetermined variable in an 'If' statement

Tags: c++

First off, I just started learning C++, so please forgive me if I titled this incorrectly, or I don't know what something means. If you do answer this question, please don't use all those crazy vocabulary words that I wouldn't know. Thanks :).

I am currently (trying) to make a calculator, that give you a choice to either add subtract, multiply, or divide. I know this doesn't seem like something that would be very helpful, but of the things I have done, I have learned a lot from it.

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int add() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int sum;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    sum = x + y;

    cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << sum << endl;
}

int subtract() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int difference;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    difference = x - y;

    cout << x << " - " << y << " = " << difference << endl;
}

int multiply() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int product;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    product = x * y;

    cout << x << " * " << y << " = " << product << endl;
}

int divide() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int quotient;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    quotient = x / y;

    cout << x << " / " << y << " = " << quotient << endl;
}


int main()
{
    int Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide;
    string str;

    cout << "Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide?: ";

    getline(cin, str);
    if (str == (cin, add));
    cout << "Starting process " << str << "..." << endl;
        add();


    getline(cin, str);
    if (str == (cin, "subtract"));
    cout << "Starting process " << str << "..." << endl;
        subtract();    

}
```

The Issue I am having, is in the `main()` part. I want the program to read the user input via `getline` and then have it compare it to a predetermined variable. Then, I tried to make an if statement, that, if the user input was for instance "add", then the if statement reads that, and then runs my `add` function.

I got as far as the `getline` part, but as you can see, the if statement does nothing. I was thinking it might be something like:

```
if (str == "add")
cout << "Starting Process" << str << "..." << endl;
    add();
```

All that got me was some errors. I'm not sure how to construct the `if` statement, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Nick

Comment: Is your debugger broken? What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line?

Comment: Could you post what the errors that you got?

Comment: What do you think `(cin, add)` does?  Time to get a real C++ reference and quality lesson book.

Comment: You need brackets around your if statement for multiple commands. `if (/* condition */) { /* code */ }`

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some research, and I got this to finally work. I apologize if this caused you any inconvenience. I can see though, that this is a very active and nice community. I will make sure to come back to it as a "first line of defence". Here is my final code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void add() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int sum;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    sum = x + y;

    cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << sum << endl;
}

void subtract() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int difference;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    difference = x - y;

    cout << x << " - " << y << " = " << difference << endl;
}

void multiply() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int product;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    product = x * y;

    cout << x << " * " << y << " = " << product << endl;
} 

void divide() 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int quotient;

    cout << "Enter the value for x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter the value for y: ";
    cin >> y;

    quotient = x / y;

    cout << x << " / " << y << " = " << quotient << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide;
    string str;

    cout << "Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide? (Letters are case sensitive): ";
    getline(cin, str);

    if (str == "Add")
    {
        cout << "Starting Process " << str << "..." << endl;
            add();
    }

    //getline(cin, str);
    if (str == "Subtract")
    {
        cout << "Starting process " << str << "..." << endl;
            subtract();
    }   

    //getline(cin, str);
    if (str == "Multiply")
    {
        cout << "Starting process " << str << "..." << endl;
            multiply();
    }

    //getline(cin, str);
    if (str == "Divide")
    {
        cout << "Starting process " << str << "..." << endl;
            divide();
    }

}
```

Comment: Good job on finding the answer yourself! Self answering is encouraged, but please add an explanation of why this new code worked, so it can be more helpful to others. Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!